# Piecewise exponential models with overlapping time periods

Tags: survival, interval-censoring, piecewise-pdf

I would like to fit a [piecewise exponential model](https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7s4) using survival data. However, many of the event times are interval-censored with overlapping intervals (see the example below, where each row is an interval). It seems inevitable that some events will span multiple time periods. For example, if I select the time periods [20, 25), [25, 30), [30, 35), etc. the first observation will span two intervals: [25, 30) and [30, 35). How should I handle observations like this? Essentially, I am looking for a way to model events that have a positive probability of occurring in multiple time periods.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are you fitting a piecewise exponential to? The survival time? The hazard function?

Comment: I'm fitting it to the hazard function; see the model outlined here: https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7s4